# Generating Printer Preferences XML

Tags: powershell, printers

I'm writing a script that takes the name of a printer from a csv file and for each printer it is supposed to modify a xml printer preference, change the name of the printer, generate a new guid and output the new xml file. It almost works. Problem is that the script also changes the clsid, because it has the same regex as the uid. Only the uid is supposed to change, in other words: only the second occurrence of the matching regex.

Heres what the xml file looks like:

```
<SharedPrinter clsid="{9A5E9697-9095-436d-A0EE-4D128FDFBCE5}" name="cop-fibu-eink" status="cop-fibu-eink" image="1" changed="2021-02-18 14:52:29" uid="{7D783062-5840-4CBD-BE9A-6334FD87A8D6}" removePolicy="1" userContext="1" bypassErrors="1"><Properties action="R" comment="" path="\\srv-print01\cop-fibu-eink" location="" default="1" skipLocal="0" deleteAll="0" persistent="0" deleteMaps="0" port=""/><Filters><FilterGroup bool="AND" not="0" name="EKBDOM1\cop-fibu-eink" sid="S-1-5-21-356607561-1380008178-1848903544-16152" userContext="0" primaryGroup="0" localGroup="0"/></Filters></SharedPrinter>
```

And this is the Powershell script:

```
Import-Csv .\printer_groups.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $uid = ([guid]::NewGuid()).guid
    ((Get-Content -path C:\pc_inst\druckerliste\cop-it.xml -Raw) -replace "cop-fibu-eink", $($_.name)` -replace "\{[0-9a-z\-]*\}", $uid ) | Set-Content -Path .\xmls\$($_.name).xml 
}
```

I can't figure it out. Hope you guys can help me. (:

Comment: Use `Export-Clixml` instead of `Set-Content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague figured it out. In case anyone is wondering:

```
Import-Csv C:\pc_inst\druckerliste\printer_groups.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $uid = ([guid]::NewGuid()).guid
    ((Get-Content -path C:\pc_inst\druckerliste\cop-it.xml -Raw) -replace "cop-fibu-eink", $($_.name)` -replace 'uid="\{[0-9a-z\-]*\}"', ('uid="{' + $uid + '}"') ) | Set-Content -Path C:\pc_inst\druckerliste\drucker_xml_standard\$($_.name).xml 
}
```

Comment: Mark your post as "answer" to help next people looking for the same solution :)

Comment: You should not use Regex `-replace` on an XML file. PowerShell is very capable to manipulate XML

Answer (score 0):

If your file content is xml, why not treat it as xml as opposed to plain text?

```
$oldText = @"
<SharedPrinter clsid="{9A5E9697-9095-436d-A0EE-4D128FDFBCE5}" name="cop-fibu-eink" status="cop-fibu-eink" image="1" changed="2021-02-18 14:52:29" uid="{7D783062-5840-4CBD-BE9A-6334FD87A8D6}" removePolicy="1" userContext="1" bypassErrors="1">
  <Properties action="R" comment="" path="\\srv-print01\cop-fibu-eink" location="" default="1" skipLocal="0" deleteAll="0" persistent="0" deleteMaps="0" port="" />
  <Filters>
    <FilterGroup bool="AND" not="0" name="EKBDOM1\cop-fibu-eink" sid="S-1-5-21-356607561-1380008178-1848903544-16152" userContext="0" primaryGroup="0" localGroup="0" />
  </Filters>
</SharedPrinter>
"@

$xml = [xml] $oldText;
```

and then you can change attribute values easily like this:

```
$xml.SharedPrinter.uid = "{" + [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpperInvariant() + "};
```

and serialize it back to xml:

```
$newText = $xml.OuterXml;

write-host $newText;
```

Note - it might not matter, but your original uid attribute has enclosing braces and upper case letters (`uid="{7D783062-5840-4CBD-BE9A-6334FD87A8D6}"`) so I've matched that in the new value...

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this. It's not well-structured but it Just Works(tm). It does all off the GPP stuff instead of your problem, but you can get the overall idea.

```
# Configuration variables
$PrintServer = ""
$CSVFilePath = "printers.csv"
$XMLFilePath = "printers.xml"


# The code

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Domain = (Get-ADDomain).name

$ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Now = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

# Set The Formatting
$XMLSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$XMLSettings.Indent = $true
$XMLSettings.IndentChars = "    "

# Set the File Name Create The Document
$XMLWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create($XMLfilePath, $XMLSettings)

# Write the XML Declaration
$XMLWriter.WriteStartDocument()

# Start the Root Element
$XMLWriter.WriteComment('Root of the policy')
$XMLWriter.WriteStartElement('Printers') # Start root
$XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('clsid', '{1F577D12-3D1B-471e-A1B7-060317597B9C}')


Import-Csv (Join-Path -Path $ScriptPath -ChildPath $CSVFilePath) | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupName = $_.Group
    [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup]$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter { name -like $_.GroupName }

    # Start SharedPrinter Element
    $XMLWriter.WriteStartElement('SharedPrinter') # Start SharedPrinter
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('clsid', '{9A5E9697-9095-436d-A0EE-4D128FDFBCE5}')
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('name', $_.Printer)
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('status', $_.Printer)
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('image', '1')
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('bypassErrors', '1')
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('changed', $Now)
    $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('uid', [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())

        # Start Properties Element
        $XMLWriter.WriteStartElement('Properties') # Start Properties
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('action', 'R')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('comment', '')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('path', "\\$PrintServer\$($_.Printer)")
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('location', '')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('default', $_.Default)
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('skipLocal', '0')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('deleteAll', '0')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('persistent', '0')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('deleteMaps', '0')
        $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('port', '')
        $XMLWriter.WriteEndElement() # End Properties   

        # Start Filters Element
        $XMLWriter.WriteStartElement('Filters') # Start Filters

            # Start FilterGroup Element
            $XMLWriter.WriteStartElement('FilterGroup')
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('bool', 'AND')
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('not', '0')
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('name', "$Domain\$($Group.Name)")
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('sid', $Group.SID)
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('userContext', '1')
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('primaryGroup', '0')
            $XMLWriter.WriteAttributeString('localGroup', '0')
            $XMLWriter.WriteEndElement() # End FilterGroup

        $XMLWriter.WriteEndElement() # End Filters

    $XMLWriter.WriteEndElement() # End SharedPrinter
}

$XMLWriter.WriteEndElement() # End root

# End, Finalize and close the XML Document
$XMLWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$XMLWriter.Flush()
$XMLWriter.Close()
```